# why is my rep so low?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why is my reputation on meta-so only 1? (at the time of this writing)

I participate, albeit in a small and quiet way, on 4 other SO sites (stack, super, server, area51). I've not had any significant down-votes that I'm aware of. My reps on the other sites is small but slowly growing (now that I've learned that marking a post community wiki means forsaking all points). I don't mind being small potatoes, it is a reflection of my level of involvement after all. It does suck not even being able to say "hey this question is pretty good or that comment is insightful" by giving an up vote though, and I don't want to game the system by thinking up questions just so I can garner enough points to participate meaningfully.

Comment: +1 partially because I had the same frustration until I found this question but mainly just to get you more rep points. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just get 1 account higher than 200 Rep and you will get an [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites) (Deleted post) of 100 for all the other sites.

However, since your accounts are already associated, you will have to clear your associations, then reassociate your accounts to get the bonus.

EDIT: It is no longer necessary to clear associations and reassociate your accounts to get a bonus. [Association bonusses are now awarded automagically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep)

Comment: @gnovice, is that retroactive? From the other posts, it didn't sound so. But if not, then it wouldn't help @matt any (or me, for that matter :)

Comment: @John: Once you get a single account over 200, if you dissociate and reassociate, you get the bonus.

Comment: @jon seigel, cool, thanks. Only 7 points away... Hey, any of you *10K* users got any questions you're too lazy to type up? ;)

Comment: @John C: There you are. Go crazy.

Comment: LOL - thanks, @mmyers. For the benefit of the audience, this person and I have never met or communicated elsewhere. :) And just to confirm, it works nicely, all three of my accounts got +100.

Comment: @gnovice, that's very helpful advice for when I cross the 200 threshold, thanks. It does seem to be gaming the system a bit though.

Comment: @matt: I don't see it as gaming.  I think it goes along with the spirit of the rep points. Meaning, if I have 200 points on SO, then chances are I am experienced enough to vote up and down, in general.  100 points allows me to do exactly that. I think it's more a bug than any type of "gaming."

Comment: @gmale, after reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites I agree it's more a bug more than a game, and that it is an out-in-the-open acknowledged technique. Bug report/feature request filed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/automatic-association-bonus-at-200-rep

Comment: At least as of today, it is no longer necessary to clear and then re-associate your accounts to get the bonus. No need to game the system. Just ask, answer and edit!