# Award account association bonus automatically upon reaching 200 rep

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, linked-accounts, association-bonus

Currently if a user has more than 200 rep points on one of the Stack Exchange sites, and then associates his account with another SE site account, the linked-to account gains a one time bonus of 100 points.

This is a good idea, and I understand the rationale. However, it discourages linking of accounts before that threshold is reached. It also encourages breaking existing associations and then relinking afterwards just to get the bonus. That behavior has been [suggested to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56477/why-is-my-rep-so-low/) since my accounts are already associated.

Wouldn't it be better to just grant the bonus automatically when one of the accounts reaches 200?

Comment: I think either this or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63406/schedule-a-task-to-check-for-missing-100-reputation is a dupe.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

We've been doing this for a couple weeks now without any issues (initial deploy definitely had a few...).

I'm sure there are still some edge cases, but in general everyone should get their bonus automagically when any account *crosses* the 200 rep boundary.

Comment: I really liked your use of words.

Comment: Yep! I almost fainted when I went on to SO this morning and saw +2000 rep (across all my different SE sites).

Comment: Initial answer is correct. No need to edit and change words.

Answer (score 31):

You still get the +100 points, even if the accounts are already linked at the time when you reach 200 points.

Comment: Yes: it's been happening [since the end of April 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90712/184638).

Answer (score 22):

The point of this family of sites is surely to be a means of acquiring or offering help related to programming. Rep points are a nice incentive but the main aim is having an active userbase of people who have the expertise required to help the average Joe get his job done.

If the offer or 100 points can entice a 1k contributor from Stack Overflow to Super User it *has* to be worth it. Problem configuring Zend? I'm sure there's a Zend dev with a SO account. xCode giving you grief? An army of Apple employees and app developers are there. If anything, I think a more positive push should be made to advertise the other sites. I use Stack Overflow almost exclusively,  but I bet I could be a lot more helpful on Super User (there are a lot of super talented people on Stack Overflow; it's hard to stand out). Didn't know about it until last week.

For the sake of 100 virtual points, if one in 100 people transitioning to another site spots a question they can answer and does so it is more than worth it.