# Schedule a Task to Check for Missing +100 Reputation

Tags: feature-request, linked-accounts, association-bonus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Award account association bonus automatically upon reaching 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep)

As the number of Stack Exchange sites grow, we are likely to see a huge influx of users who have not previously been exposed to the original Trilogy. These users won't have the +100 rep bonus that comes from associating accounts, and while they are likely to gain 200 rep on one site eventually, they may not be aware of the +100 rep bonus.

This hasn't been a problem so far, since most Trilogy users started on Stack Overflow and had 200 reputation before they created their SF and SU accounts (since those sites didn't exist yet). However, new users may have accounts on several sites (since there are now so many sites) before they reach 200 rep on one site.

Currently, the bonus must be manually triggered by unassociation from the accounts tab, which forces the check at the automatic reassociation.

However, this creates a gap between those in-the-know (since most users don't come to MSO) and those visitors who are less frequent/devoted to Stack Exchange. I suggest that every week/month, an automatic task is run to check for users who are eligible for the 100 rep and to award this bonus, since they deserve it even if they don't know about every tiny little feature.

Comment: I was going to ask the question how a new user gets 100 rep, since I haven't gotten that for any of my associated accounts..

Comment: A scheduled task that runs every week/month is just too slow in this modern age, man... ^_^

Comment: Similar posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56506/151244 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63489/151244 .