# Why did I get another 100 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Award account association bonus automatically upon reaching 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep)

It's not a question, just a clarification. I recently acquired the privilege of 'view close votes'. I had 244 reputation, which at a point suddenly become 344, and since then it crossed 250.  I got the mentioned privilege. What I don't understand, is the reason for the 100 rep increase, can someone clarify.  I am just curious about the reason for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you link an account that has 200 points (Stack Overflow in your case) with another account (Meta Stack Overflow), you gain 100 bonus points in each of the accounts that are linked together.

You created your Meta SO account today. Hence the 100 bonus points.

[image: Linked accounts]

Comment: I ll accept your answer, its not allowing me at this point, one more clarification, from where have you got the screenshot which you have pasted in the answer ?

Comment: @Swagatika: Go to your user profile and click on the accounts tab that will be at the middle of the page. You should see all your accounts.