# I just got a 100+ rep for no reason

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why did I get another 100 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103519/why-did-i-get-another-100-rep)
>   [Award account association bonus automatically upon reaching 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep)

I got a 100+ rep all of a sudden for no reason, as I know of.  The rep log doesn't show anything about 100+.

Comment: There, my down vote got rid of two, just need 49 more people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit this url https://askubuntu.com/reputation. This will show you the complete list of points and also any bonuses that you might have got on http://askbuntu.com.

On any SE site, you can navigate to `<site url>/reputation`.

If you hit the `Trigger Reputation Recalc` button, your reputation will be up to date. You can trigger the recalc only once a day.

Comment: I found out I got a bunch of up votes on my questions in a very small period of time, which made it look "magical"