# Why is the bonus 100 points set for 200 points in a single site and not set to a combination of sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, association-bonus

The stack exchange umbrella is getting wider and for some of us living just on one site is not ideal.

When questions that used to be housed on one board are now housed on two boards.  For example: [Connect to a VPN from a Linux Virtual Machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52069/connect-to-a-vpn-from-a-linux-virtual-machine) could have been put on the Ubuntu site.

By spreading points around different sites it is possible to earn more than double the 200 point barrier and not have the most basic privileges on new sites.

Why have we limited the 100 point bump to just a single site?

I am wondering if there was some reasoning for this not being implemented or if it just hasn't been proposed yet.

Comment: So, when there are 200 sites, just register on them all, and have an aggregate of 200 points just by registering, suddenly gaining 100 association on each?

Comment: @Oded I assume the single initial rep point wouldn't contribute to that.

Comment: @JanDvorak - well, if we did implement it, it probably wouldn't. But still, the point is not the amount of rep - it is the experience gained on one site that matters.

Comment: Why would it matter the experience was gained on a single site? It's the same amount of experience in either case.

Answer (score 15):

Gaining 20 rep on 10 sites is very different from gaining 200 on one.

The latter shows some engagement in a community. It shows someone has spent some time and learned how the system works. So they do not need to learn it over and over again.

That's the point of the association bonus. Not simply "get 200" - it is the getting them one a site and learning in the process that's important.

Comment: Why can't I learn by contributing to more than one community instead?

Comment: @JanDvorak - sure, you can, but how can we determine that? High rep on one site is more indicative of learning and investing yourself in the well being of a site than low rep across a number of sites.

Comment: @Oded.  You seem to be stuck on the finite implementation details instead of the idea.  A filter to remove all sites under 60 points could be made, you could pick the top 4, the 200 could be 400 to counteract your join every site idea.  We are a group of intelligent people that does recognize that systems can be exploited and we fix them.   [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep?rq=1) for example.

Comment: @DarkSheep - that's funny. Given that my point is about determining familiarity and knowledge of the community, the platform and how it works. What I have given were examples of why this doesn't work as suggested - why there is value in keeping it to 200, on one site.

Comment: @Oded You speak in a *disgustingly* condescending tone. Obviously the bonus was added as a hack to encouraged use of other SE sites and has not been revised or considered in any depth since. It makes no sense that on one hand you say a user needs to understand the platform, but to do this they must restrict themselves to a single site within it. In theory, that may or may not make sense, but it's a really just a refusal to consider any data or criticism of the topic.

Comment: agree that this is "finite implementation details". I'm intrigued that this hasn't come up, been [implemented?] thoroughly investigated/considered before? [I suppose I thought SE was larger]