# Reputation across Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, reputation, stack-exchange

I am new to Stack Exchange and have participated in two sites. I want to know if reputation works across Stack Exchange sites.

For example, if I have 20 reputation points in Ask Ubuntu, can I post a comment on Super User? Or should I earn reputation separately in each site of Stack Exchange to be able to use the privileges of reputed user?

Are there any specific sites in Stack Exchange that allow cross reputation?

I am signing in with my Google account.  Will that affect the way reputation works?

Looking at the questions pointed out, I can see the questions themselves do not address the issue I have asked. Only the answers deal with them. So I don't think the question is duplicate, unless of course it is expected of me to read all questions about reputation before asking a new one.

Besides this question deals with a very specific issue rather than being over generalised. I think future new users will benefit from this.

Comment: Each site has its own rep. Privileges earned on one don't effect the other, unless you have 200 or more rep and get the [association bonus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep).

Comment: So is it like a newly created account for each site?

Comment: Yes you can have a separate account on each site/community of Stack Exchange, and if they are all associated you see them all listed in your "Accounts" tab and get +100 rep in all of them once you reach 200 in one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each site has its own reputation, privileges and bounties.

The only cross effect is the association bonus - the first time you hit 200 reputation points on any site, you'll be awarded a bonus of 100 reputation points on all the sites, including the one you hit 200 on, and including new sites you'll join later on (so your starting reputation points on those sites will be 101, not 1).