# Do I get more reputation when another StackOverflow account reaches 200?

Tags: support, reputation, association, association-bonus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do reputation bonuses for associations between accounts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work)

In some place I heared that if I link an account from an Stack Exchange page to another that has more than 200 rep, then the first account will have +100 rep.

I recently reached 200 rep on my Stack Overflow account, however none of my other accounts (that I have aready linked) on SuperUser and ServerFault got more points. How does this work?

Comment: Decouple all your accounts and then relink them. Bingo, bango, 100 points and there you go.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56477/why-is-my-rep-so-low/56478#56478) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites).

Comment: Long history: before logging in to Super User of Server Fault, I de-associated those two from Stack OVerflow. Now, when I logged in to those it gave me the message of +100 reputation, but I had no new reputation. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure? On SU it shows you have +100 from the association.

Comment: It can take a few minutes while changes propagate through the system and caches are cleared.  Some "immediately" awarded badges can take two days to appear.

Comment: Yup, and for some reason I didn't get +100 at SU (I already had about 190 points), but got +100 at SO. Weird.